# SQL Trigger creation The multi-part identifier "ALIAS" could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some trouble with DB while making trigger.

My task is to check the balance of all accounts when there is new transaction completed and if balance is doesn't equal 0 i must rollback the transaction.

My query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkBalance
ON dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION
AFTER UPDATE
AS
IF dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID  = 'COMPLETED'  - !!! Error line
BEGIN
    Declare @sumBalance NUMERIC = (select SUM(CURRENT_BALANCE) from dbo.ACCOUNT_DETAILS)
        IF @sumBalance != 0 ROLLBACK
END
```

Error message
The multi-part identifier "dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION.STATUS_ID" could not be bound.

I hope someone help me. Thanks in advance!

BTW i've made shi*** resolving, but i don't think that would be right:

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkBalance
ON dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION
AFTER UPDATE
AS
Declare @checkStatus char (36) = (select TOP 1 STATUS_ID 
from dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION
order by dbo.ONLINE_TRANSACTION.CREATED_ON DESC)
IF @checkStatus = 'COMPLETED'
BEGIN
    Declare @sumBalance NUMERIC = (select SUM(CURRENT_BALANCE) as Balance from dbo.ACCOUNT_DETAILS)
        IF @sumBalance != 0 ROLLBACK
END
```

It would be wonderful if someone spend his own time explaining why i recieved an error. I was looking for answer but didn't find anything with triggers, most resoves connected with bad alias and inner joins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE STATUS_ID  = 'COMPLETED')
BEGIN
 ....
END
```

`inserted` special table holds information from the updated records. It may contain more than one records. Thus, the predicate in the `IF` statement above will be true if *at least one* updated record has `STATUS_ID  = 'COMPLETED'`.

Comment: Interesting way of getting status. Thanks a lot. Going to test the trigger.